# Start a process on click

Tags: python, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I am trying to add multiprocessing to my project. To exemplify, I made a little project with just a button, and when the button is pressed, I want to start a process with a method, but the method is never called.
How could I call the method within a process?

Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        button = QPushButton("CLICK", self)
        button.setGeometry(200, 150, 100, 30)

        proc = Process(target=self.button_clicked)
        procs = []
        procs.append(proc)

        button.clicked.connect(proc.start)

    def button_clicked(self):
        print("pressed")


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: can't you move `button_clicked` outside of class into a function or put it in its separate class ?

Comment: the fact that you want to serialize a method of a GUI class means that you either want to  modify the GUI from the function, or check properties of GUI in the function, both of which will either never work reliably or result in a segmentation fault in almost all cases as these things are not threadsafe, not to mention process-safe ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally mixing both Qt GUI objects and anything that allows threading/multiprocessesing is not safe, and will either not work or cause a segmentation fault.

the correct way to do it without crashing your application is to move the target function to be a function that doesn't relate to QT GUI. (not a member of any Qt GUI object or has a reference to any Qt GUI object)

also processes can only start once, so you need to create one on every button press as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

def some_function():
    print("hello")

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)
        self.UiComponents()
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        button = QPushButton("CLICK", self)
        button.setGeometry(200, 150, 100, 30)

        self.procs = []

        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def button_clicked(self):
        proc = Process(target=some_function)
        self.procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":  # for windows compatibility
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

the button is connected to a function which belongs to a Qt object, but the process is connected to a function that is not in any way connected to Qt, and will therefore not crash your application.